# The /v1.0/me endpoint preferredLanguage property source

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I was told that the `preferredLanguage` property of the `/me` endpoint would reflect the values in the users Delve profile. The [user object docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) lists it as

> The preferred language for the user. Should follow ISO 639-1 Code; for example "en-US".

Although the user has selected languages in their Delve profile at https://nam.delve.office.com/. The `/me` endpoint does not reflect those changes, some 2 weeks later.

I'm wondering if the source for this value is AD and if so, any plans to update it so that it can reflect the user's selection.

Comment: Where exactly in the Delve profile are you updating the selected languages? I couldn't find it in My account settings https://portal.office.com/account/#settings or Delve Edit profile screen...

Comment: If you click "Update Profile" and then scroll down there are three "questions".  The second one is "How can I change language and regional settings?"... if you click on the link it takes you to the users SharePoint profile (my site) and then if you click the ... you can select "Language and Region".  On that screen you can change your language preferences. Convoluted I know, and that's part of the pain.

Comment: doesn't that answer your own question then? As that link jumps you into the old SharePoint MY Site url to update profile information. So if you change it there, your question specifically is .... Does "PreferredLanguage" property come from SharePoint User Profiles for its source?

Comment: Running /me?$whatif shows it is calling 
{"Description":"Execute HTTP request","Uri":"https://graph.windows.net/v2/dcd219dd-bc68-4b9b-bf0b-4a33a796be35/users('48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038')?$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id","HttpMethod":"GET"}

What is interesting, is that in portal.azure.com in the profile editor fora user. PreferredLanguage is not there.

Comment: I can confirm that `preferredLanguage` is pulled from the AAD `DirectoryObject`. What is interesting however is that it is _read-only_. Often this implies that the property is being populated by an external service (such as how `mailNickname` is populated by Exchange Online).  Another common reason for this is when a property is populated/owned by an on-prem AD instance and imported into AAD by AAD Connect. I'm afraid that is the extent of my knowledge on this but hopefully it provides some clues.

Comment: Yes I was aware that it's part of SharePoint's MY Site, but as I said originally we were informed that the information fed through to the Microsoft Graph... and yes, it seems like it might be AAD/AD sourced instead but that does little good if a, you can't update it and/or b, it can only be done by an administrator. Regardless, not a problem I suspect that the Microsoft Graph team can solve but thank you for the direction.

Comment: Just an update here. The Profile API was announced at Ignite in Preview.

The team is actually working with the office team to fix this for both consumer and enterprise – so it’s mastered by Profile API in future and possible to change – from there the experiences will key off that value to render the appropriate content.